# Field 'tax_override' doesn't have a default value

Tags: expresso-store

Working with the default templates in Expresso-Store and am getting the following error when trying to add to cart; please note that the default tax rate has been set.

Error Number: 1364

Field 'tax_override' doesn't have a default value

insert into `exp_store_orders` (`order_hash`, `billing_same_as_shipping`, `billing_country`, `billing_state`, `shipping_country`, `shipping_state`, `shipping_method`, `weight_units`, `dimension_units`, `site_id`, `order_date`, `ip_address`, `ip_country`, `return_url`, `cancel_url`) values ('dd3c64ebe03881dd2dbc8d33185332c2', 1, 'US', 'NE', 'US', 'NE', '', 'lb', 'in', '1', 1467737126, '70.184.219.242', NULL, 'http://www.heartlandclassics.info/store_example/product/related-product-test', 'http://www.heartlandclassics.info/store_example/product/related-product-test')

Filename: third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db/src/CodeIgniterConnection.php

Line Number: 145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that we needed to turn off strict MySQL on the server and the tax issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found this question and the solution from 92 West. A better way is to go into the database and change the default value for the 'tax_override' field from 'none' to NULL.